# Best practice for MySql unique identifying key columns

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

This is just a generalized example.  I have a somewhat static MySQL database reference table with a few dozen rows of data.  The structure of the table looks like the following:

```
video_games
id             int(11)
release_date   datetime
title          varchar(64)
msrp           float
```

I have a separate table called 'users' with a 'favorite_video_game_id' column that can point to the 'id' column in 'video_games'.

On a site I'd built, I had a special page specifically for displaying usernames of people who are fans of several specific games ("Overwatch", "Warcraft" and "Diablo").  To pull back the game information and the users who liked them, I had a mysql statment similar to the following:

```
select u.*, vg.* 
from users u, video_games vg 
where u.favorite_video_game_id = vg.id and vg.title= 'Warcraft';
```

At a certain point I realized that I wanted to have a more specific name for the game in the database, "World of Warcraft", and so I updated the title in the database.  When I went back to my page, however, I realized that the game information and information list were showing as empty, because the 'title' column had changed, and I now needed to update all of my code.

When I realized all of the titles that I wanted to expand to more fuller names, and all of  the code changes I would need to make on the site, it felt to me like my PHP code was being tightly coupled to the SQL data, like I was hardcoding content data into my PHP file.  My first thought was to change the mysql code to reference the IDs directly, like the following:

```
select u.*, vg.* 
from users u, video_games vg 
where u.favorite_video_game_id = vg.id and vg.id= 13;
```

However, I've read that using primary key columns directly like that is discouraged, since there could be instances in the future where the ids have to be changed, or the data is transferred to another database vendor, and the ids would no longer be correct.

My next thought was to add another index key column, maybe a random hash value, that would also be unique to the video game and wouldn't hit the above issue.  But it seems a bit weird/redundant to add another unique key column when there's already the id column, and I was wondering if I might be missing/overlooking something as far as uniquely identifying the rows without coupling my PHP to a content column in the database.

What would be the best design practice in this sort of situation?  Thanks.

Comment: Just curious, where did you read that using primary key columns is discouraged? Never heard about this before, I want to find out the reason it says that.

Comment: There's always some risk (however small) that data could change, regardless of whether it's the IDs or the movie titles. I'd say the risk of IDs changing without you knowing is fairly small, as that would severely limit the reliability of typical relational databases. The risk of titles changing might be equally small if the table is treated as static. If you must hardcode values that reference entries, I might just update them to the new titles, especially if this is just a one-time change.

Comment: That being said, if you're worried about IDs changing (for example, you might change database engines or you're using a distributed environment), you could use server-generated IDs instead of database-generated IDs. See [Why Did We Shift Away From Database-Generated Ids?](https://medium.com/ingeniouslysimple/why-did-we-shift-away-from-database-generated-ids-7e0e54a49bb3)

Comment: @catcon It was a standard rule of thumb at a large (read: multi-million dollar global) consulting firm I worked at back when I was in Java development and worked in Oracle RDBMS.  TBH, ever since I got into PHP development, I've been appalled at some of the database practices I've seen from web developers at smaller companies, and so I'm trying to fish for best practices here for handling these sorts of tight coupling issues.

Comment: You might also consider asking [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Every table _should_ have a `PRIMARY KEY`.  Unlike other vendors, in MySQL, a PK is `UNIQUE`, a key, and 'clustered'.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I should have said "video game" instead of "movie".

Comment: Please learn to use the new syntax for `JOINs`:  not `FROM a,b WHERE...`; instead `FROM a JOIN b ON ... WHERE other stuff`

Comment: @showdev  Server-generated IDs definitely sounds like a step in the right direction, since it helps ensure the primary keys can be consistent across database vendors, and recognizes that usable keys are more important for the application than the database.  Great article too.

Answer (score 0):

I voted up first answer because it basically describe how you supposed to engineer your DB structure, and he is right. If you have to use a unique key in third table you can use an `email`, `phone` or any other key which will be unique in your user table and on the same way at game table: if you have a unique id in there too, you are more then welcome to use that in third table. Basically third table what it does, it just associate your two tables like user and games.

Answer (score 0):

To formalize what several comments have already said, there is nothing whatsoever wrong with using a table's primary key to establish a relationship. In fact, it is expected and is a "best practice". You should never try to create a relationship based on a volatile field, unless you add the safety mechanisms to update all references when a value changes. Some of that is built into MySQL, but that primary key is a steady rock you can tie your boat to.

Simply, there are never times when an item's primary key changes. If it's a different primary key, it's a different item, by definition.

I get the feeling you understand this fundamentally, but either misread good advice or read bad advice perfectly. But I'm here to tell you - this is what primary keys are for. Use `game_id` in your `favorite_video_game_id` column and move on happily.

Comment: Considerations might include: "What if we want to change data storage system with a one which [can't generate] auto-increment primary keys?... [E]ach data storage system has different ways of generating these identifiers which may [generate] a different primitive type.... [W]hen we have a table in our SQL Server database with generated primary keys, we don’t have an easy way to scale this table horizontally in a distributed environment." --[Id Generation on the Server vs. Database](https://medium.com/ingeniouslysimple/why-did-we-shift-away-from-database-generated-ids-7e0e54a49bb3#d0a7).

Comment: That's why i proposed a unique key to be based on email or any other field which will be unique in thous two tables. In this case we skip on dealing with primary keys generating or not in other data storages.